# find a differential equation for a volume mixer problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A tank contains 1000L of pure water. Brine that contains 0.05kg of salt per liter of water enters the tank at a rate of 5L/min. Brine that contains 0.04kg of salt per liter of water enters the tank at a rate of 10 L / min. The solution is kept thoroughly mixed and drains from the tank at a rate of 15 L / min. How much salt is in the tank (a) after $t$ minutes?

Let $y(t)$ be the amount of salt (in kg) after $t$ minutes. The amount of salt at t = 0 is $y(0) = 0$.

I know the general direction I want to go in is $$ \frac{dy}{dt} = \textrm{rate in} + \textrm{rate in} - \textrm{rate out}$$

I observe that the brine with .004kg of salt content enters at 2x the amount compared to the brine with .05kg so I think I want to set up some sort of proportion? Here is what I have so far and I think I want to make the units line up better, but my head is spinning right now and I'm not sure in what direction to go from here.

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \bigg(\frac{0.05kg}{L} \cdot \frac{5L}{min}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{0.04kg}{L} \cdot \frac{10L}{min}\bigg)-\bigg(\frac{15L}{min}\bigg)$$

edit:

---

Alright I think I got the formula to be $$\frac{dy}{dt} = .65 - \frac{y(t)}{66.67})  \\ \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{.975 - y(t)}{66.67}$$

Just want a confirmation my setup is correct, and I can do the rest of the math from here

Comment: I made a couple of edits to add the addition and subtraction signs and make clear that the liters are part of the concentration expressions.  Note that each term is in terms of  kg/min...except the last one.  That last one is what you need to fix.

Comment: @Paul how does it look?

Comment: Looks good! There should be a decimal point for the 65 in the first equation, but the second is correct.

Comment: whoops typo,  thanks for the help!